# Install button not working (third party app) on Nexus 5X

Tags: installation, nexus-5x, non-market

I am unable to click on `install` button. I have made back up some of my apps. But now when I'm clicking on the install button, it's not working. Cancel button is working nicely. I purchased it 3 days ago. I didn't install any app that is related to screen brightness. I googled for this problem, I found an issue with screen brightness app. I didn't install any kind of these apps. I'm using Marshmallow 6.0.
Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

At last I got the solution. I didn't install any screen filter app. But in Nexus 5X, there is an option which controls screen brightness.
Make Adaptive Brightness turned on, you can find it in `Settings > Display > Adaptive Brightness > ON`. That's it, now you can install any app form any source.